# Enable auto-code completion in SQL Developer for a Sybase connection

Tags: sql, sybase, code-completion

I am connecting to a Sybase 12.5 database using Oracle SQL Developer tool. This is acheived by using a third party jar (jtds-1.2.5.jar).
I am able to connect and execute queries on DB successfully but Code completeion (Ctrl-Space) is not available for Table names and Columns.
I have checked the preferences and it is enabled but it is not working.
In the past i have seen this working fine for an Oracle database but it is not working for Sybase database.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to Oracle's OTN, Code Completion is only available for Oracle DB's.

> "The third-party connectivity is
>   mainly there to support migration. It
>   isn't intended to be a full featured
>   multi-database tool." (Dec 2010)
>   http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9197701�

I added a feature request to the SQL Developer Exchange: OTN, SQL Developer Exchange, Feature Request on the left side, search for title "Code Completion (Code insight) for Third Party (Sybase ect)". If we all vote than some day...